# iOS Slide in UIView on top of other UIView

Tags: ios, facebook, menu, slide, slidingmenu

I need to present of a menu UIView on top of my main UIView. This happens when the user clicks the square button as illustrated in the picture. It´s kinda of a facebook app layout except the main view is not pushed away, it´s still in position but with the menu view on top of it.

The menu is supposed to be around 80% in screen width and sliding in from left when clicking the square button.

Every possible non-external-lib solution I´ve tried so far failed so I´m really need some help with this one. Code examples or a push in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

**Requirements**: No external libs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook Navigation](https://github.com/BenHall/ios_facebook_style_navigation)

Here is an app demo that you can try to use the code from